# Android Google App Indexing - Does the start method need to be run in onStart override?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

This might seem like a bit lame question but I haven't found any other examples where the method would be run anywhere else other than in an override of an onStart method of an activity. (also the Google App Indexing documentation is not very good)

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mClient.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mClient, getAction()); //
  }
```

However in our app we do not have all the data we need to actually build the action that is being passed in the start method. Therefore in onResume I am kicking off a thread that loads the data in the background and then I am calling the start method.

I am just wondering if this start needs to be called in onStart otherwise it might prevent the App Indexing. To my observation it should not but I am not 100% sure as I have seen only those onStart examples.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi

Xamarins example:

https://blog.xamarin.com/connect-with-your-users-with-google-search-and-app-indexing/

Comment: Did you find the solution ? In my case I am getting details from server so I can not send on onStart.

Comment: @Tasneem when I can I call it on start but at some places i am calling it even after "OnResume" has been called. I don't believe it makes a difference. Am I sure about it? No. :)